# Valor da variável aumenta +1 dentro da Thread

Tags: c#, loop, variáveis, thread

Estou tentando mudar a cor da linha do DataGrid e isto é fácil. No entanto, algo está acontecendo com o valor da variável **idxRow2** quando esta é acessada na na nova Thread.

O problema está na função **BeginInvoke** do controle do **DataGrid**.

Segue código:

```
        for (int idxRow2 = 0; idxRow2 < values.Length; idxRow2++)
        {
            if (values[idxRow2][3] == fName)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Idx: " + idxRow2 + " | Name: " + fName);

                dataGridViewDownloader.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate () { dataGridViewDownloader.Rows[idxRow2].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; dataGridViewDownloader.Update(); });
            }
        }
```

Como visto acima, fiz um breve debug com a mensagem, no entanto, a variável **idxRow2** diz um valor na mensagem e no debug do erro do VS a variável idxRow2 retorna o valor do loop +1.

Alguém sabe explicar o porque que isso acontece?

Comment: O BeginInvoke não necessariamente inicia uma Thread no momento em que ele é chamado, talvez você possa criar uma variavel temporária tempIdxRow2, armazenar a informação de idxRow2 antes de chamar o BeginInvoke e, dentro do delegate, usar esta variavel temporária(nunca testei esta abordagem mas talvez resolva).

Comment: Opa Guilher, tranquilo?
Resolvi isso trocando BeginInvoke  por apenas Invoke.
Não sei ainda o que ocasiona esse +1 no valor da variável...